# Cell references in formulae

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Before the latest 365 upgrade, if I double clicked an Excel spreadsheet cell containing a formula, the actual cells referenced in the formula were highlighted in colour.  This facility seems to have vanished.  Does anyone know how I get it back? Thanks.

Comment: Repair your office installation. Nothing has changed in terms of Excel highlighting cells/ranges in formula.

Comment: If reparing Office is not helpful, you can also try to roll back Office via Run command. The command is `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.XXXXX.XXXXX`. Please note, it is for 64-bit, XXXXX.XXXXX is the build number which you can find in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date according to update channel.